# PHP Oracle transaction insert error

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I've wasted enough time on this and I need your help. It's probably a simple oversight but I use this function to connect to an oracle database a perform a transaction:

```
function transaction($query, $loop, $read_only, $return_vals){
     $DEBUG = 'yes';

    $db_name_idde = "server";
    $db_user_idde = "schema";
    $db_pass_idde = "password";

    $connection = oci_new_connect($db_user_idde, $db_pass_idde, $db_name_idde);

    $return_vars = array();

    //foreach always needs an array
    if( gettype($query) == 'string'){
        $query = array(0 => $query);
    }

    foreach($query as $statement){

        $stid = oci_parse($connection, $statement);

        if (!$stid && $DEBUG == "yes") {
            die(oci_error($connection));
        } else if (!$stid) {
            die('Could Not Execute Query.');
        }


        if ( !oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT) && $DEBUG == "yes") {

        // If we have a problem, rollback then die
            oci_rollback($connection);
            oci_close($connection);

            die($statement);
            //die(oci_error($stid));
        } else if ( !oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT) ) {
            oci_rollback($connection);
            oci_close($connection);

            die('Could Not Execute Query.');
        }
    }

    oci_commit($connection);
    oci_close($connection);

    // See if we need to send the results back
    if ($return_vals) {
        if ($loop) {
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, (OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC))) {
                $return_vars[$i] = $row;

                $i ++;
            }
        } else {
            $return_vars = oci_fetch_array($stid, (OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC));
        }
    } else {
        //$return_vars = mysql_insert_id($connection);
    }

    global $db_num_results;
    global $zero;
    $db_num_results = $i;
    $zero = 0;

    return $return_vars;
}
```

Now this function can process Updates but always fails with inserts, INSERT INTO or INSERT ALL, **claiming** a duplicate key for the randomly generated OBJECTID. I started using mt_rand instead and it generates much longer IDs than anything in the DB so it shouldn't make this claim at all:

```
INSERT ALL

INTO table1 (OBJECTID, OUTFALL_ID, INVESTIGATION_ID, LOGGED_DATE,LOGGED_BY,ASSET_ID,SOURCE,COMMENTS,STATUS, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) 
VALUES ( 1314897731, '10C10010', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '-' || sequence.NEXTVAL,  TO_DATE('05/15/2014','mm/dd/yyyy'),'person','','Sample','','Open', 'a@b.com', SYSDATE)

INTO table2 (OBJECTID, OUTFALL_ID, INVESTIGATION_ID, TASK_DATE,TASK_TIME,ENTERED_BY,TASK_TYPE,DOCUMENT_LINK,SUMMARY, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) 
VALUES ( 1314897731, '10C10010', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '-' || sequence.CURRVAL,  TO_DATE('05/24/2014','mm/dd/yyyy'),'','person','Initial Inspection','','', 'a@b.com', SYSDATE) SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

However when I run this statement in TOAD there aren't any complaints and there shouldn't be considering the new IDs I'm generating are at least 10x the size of the ones currently in there. Maybe I left some PL/SQL in there, or its accidentally repeating itself. I don't know.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Whoops forgot that in the title, its PHP.

Comment: Why don't you use a oracle sequence for objectid?

Comment: Because the OBJECTID will be provided at a later date, I'm just using a random number as a placeholder for the required field for now.

Comment: These statements puzzle me : you insert into table1 ( a table )  and in the values clause one of the values is table1.NEXTVAL (a sequence pseudo column). Is table1 a table or a sequence? In table2 insert you use CURRVAL.

Comment: Hmmm, a horrible blunder on my part, I renamed things so that I don't post company code. I fixed it, it now says sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this:

```
!oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT)
```

For some reason this forced the unique constraint error which is unusual considering it returns true/false and could be used in the if statement's conditional. Changing it to

```
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
if(!$r && $DEBUG == 'YES'){
```

removed the error. This does not explain why updates worked correctly but I have not had any more trouble since I enacted this change.